# Get Smartwatch sensor data

Tags: dataset, android-watch

I need sensor data recorded by the smart watch to create data set. I tried to get the solution from various websites but not working.

Do I need any APIs or any third party platform, which can record sensor data? Can I retrieve it using Bluetooth or direct via USB?